# matrix indexing with another matrix returning "subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals"

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Trying to understand matrix indexing.

```
A = [2 3 0 0 5; 3 0 0 0 0];
B = [1 1 0 0 1; 1 0 0 0 0];
```

When I run

```
A(1, B(1, :))
```

I was expecting

```
[2 3 5]
```

But instead, I get the error:

```
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `logical`:

```
>> A(1, logical(B(1, :)))
ans =
     2     3     5
```

Since `B` is actually a `double` array, it thinks you are trying to index element `0`, which causes the error.

Or, if you prefer double negation, do `A(1, ~~B(1, :))`. Personally, I think that looks ugly. Or simply test: `A(1, B(1, :)==1)`, `A(1, B(1, :)~=0)`, `A(1, B(1, :)>0)`, etc.

The other solution is to use `find` to satisfy the "positive integers" part of the error:

```
>> A(1, find(B(1, :)))
ans =
     2     3     5
```